# Spring JPA Repository: What is the best practice, use findAllById or iterate over IDs and call getReferenceById

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

So, I'm in a situation where I need to get the reference of some entities in the database to vinculate them with another entity that has a relationship with them. Still, I doubt what is the better approach to achieve this.

I read some people saying that the *repository.**getReferenceById**()* throws an exception if the entity doesn't exist with the given ID and, if it exists, will load it in lazy mode. That's good because I don't need to access any attribute of the entity.

And the *repository.**findAllById**()* will return a list with all the entities found. Correct me if I'm wrong, but this method returns a list where the entities are also loaded in lazy mode.

So, I want to know the best approach to fetch the entity's reference to associate it with another.

Some example code are below:

```
// 1º Approach, using findAllById

List<Integer> themesIds = service.getThemesIds();  // This line is just to illustrate the flux

List<Theme> themesReference = themeRepository.findAllById(themesIds);

anotherEntity.setThemes(themesReference);
```

```
// 2º Approach, iterate over IDs and call getReferenceById

List<Integer> themesIds = service.getThemesIds();  // This line is just to illustrate the flux

List<Theme> themesReference = themesIds.stream()
                                       .map(id-> themeRepository.getReferenceById(id))
                                       .collect(Collectors.toSet());

anotherEntity.setThemes(themesReference);
```

I think the first approach will result in only one query to fetch the entities, which may be better, and the second will perform N queries to fetch the entities, which I feel is worst.

Which one should I use?

If you know another way to do this, share it with me

Comment: This is an opinion base question, I think and it's now allowed here. Anyhow, the idea is to let the database engine to do all the "heavy" tasks, your code should not. Besides that, in the second approach, you are going to call the repository many times, this is not good.

Comment: Depending on the use case, you can include `List<Theme> themesReference` as a `@OneToMany` on `anotherEntity`, though this depends on the use case you have. If thats not possible, then performance wise, the first approach will most probably be faster. AFAIK you will be loading the whole object (with lazy dependencies) in the first approach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest the second approach because the `getReferenceById` method calls the `getReference` method of the underlying `EntityManager`, which only instantiates and returns a proxy object using the provided primary key value, **without** querying the database.

The first approach is considered an anti-pattern when using it to reference entity associations since there is always an additional query executed.

For reference: [FindById Anti-Pattern](https://vladmihalcea.com/spring-data-jpa-findbyid/), [How and when to use JPA’s getReference() Method](https://thorben-janssen.com/jpa-getreference/)

Comment: While this seems correct, you should mention that `getReference()` also returns a reference even if the ID does not actually exist in the database and will throw an exception on first access. Thus if you want to ensure that the object exists, `find()` should be used

Comment: So, even if I use a loop for getting the entities references, it will be faster since no query is executed afterall, right?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer that's correct. The exception would eventually be thrown when `save` method is called in this case.

Comment: @RafaelFurtado exactly.